# Understanding memory sequences and std::memory_order_relaxed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am studying C++ memory sequences, but it's very confusing.

For example:

```
void sumUp(std::atomic<int>& sum, std::vector<int>& val)
{
   int tmpSum = 0;
   for(auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i) tmpSum += val[i];

   sum.fetch_add(tmpSum, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

I don't understand that `sum.fetch_add()` operates after `tmpSum += val[i]`.
Since it is not in order, can `sum.fetch_add()` operate before `tmpSum += val[i]`?

So is the sum **0** possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: As a completely unrelated, you don't modify `val` in your function so it's better passed by constref: `std::vector<int> const &val`.

Comment: Worth watching this excelent talk on std::atomic if your studing them https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Answer (score 4):

`memory_order` has no observable effect in the context of a single thread:

Let's see (`x`, `a` and `b` are initially `0`):

```
auto t1(std::atomic<int>& x, int& a, int& b)
{
    a = 3;                                       // 1
    b = 5;                                       // 2
    x.store(a, std::memory_order_relaxed);       // 3
}
```

Because (1) and (2) are not dependent one on another, the compiler can reorder them. E.g. can do (1) -> (2) or (2) -> (1)

Because (3) depends on (1) ((1) writes to `a` and (3) reads from `a`) the compiler cannot do (3) before (1). This is regardless of what memory order is specified in (3)

Because (3) does not depend on (2), normally in a single-threaded model, the compiler could  do (3) before (2).

But since `x` is atomic consider another thread doing this (`x`, `a` and `b` are references to the same arguments as provided to `t1` and are all initially `0`):

```
auto t2(std::atomic<int>& x, int& a, int& b)
{
    while(x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 3)  // 4
        assert(b == 5);                            // 5
}
```

This thread waits until `x` is `3` and then asserts that `b` is `5`. Now you can see how in a sequential single threaded world (2) and (3) can be reordered without any observable behavior, but in a multi threaded model, the order of (2) and (3) could have an impact on the behavior of the program.

This is what `memory_order` does: it specifies if operations that could have been reordered before or after the atomic without any effect on a single thread can be reordered as such or not. The reason is that they could have an effect on a multi-threaded program. The compiler cannot know this, only the programmer, hence the extra `memory_order` parameter.

With `memory_order_relaxed` the assert could fail because (2) could happen after (3), but with `memory_order_seq_cst` (default) the assert will never fail, because `(2)` happens before (3).

---

Coming back to your example, regardless of what  `memory_order` you specify, it is guaranteed that `tmpSum += val[i];` will happen before `sum.fetch_add(tmpSum, std::memory_order_relaxed);` because the second one depends on the first. The `memory_order` would affect the possible reordering of instructions that do not affect the atomic operations. E.g. if you would have had a `int unrelated = 24`.

---

Btw, the official terminology is "sequenced before" and "sequenced after"

---

In the real world hardware makes things are a bit more complicated. Operations can appear in one order in the current thread, but another thread can *see* them in another order, so stricter `memory_order`s have to employ extra measures to ensure consistent order across threads.

---

Strictly speaking in this example if using `memory_order_relaxed` we would have Undefined Behavior because the access to `b` is not synchronized across threads.

Answer (score 1):

> So the sum is 0 possible??

No it's not. `std::memory_order_relaxed` says that *concurrent accesses to `sum`* are generally not ordered; in the meantime, in this particular thread, the computation of `tmpSum` is *sequenced before* `fetch_add`, so the value passed to `fetch_add` is consistent with the value computed in the loop. So, `fetch_add` does not guarantee in what order all the particular threadwise `tmpSum`s are added across all the threads, but that does not matter at all since integral addition commutes; but language semantics guarantees that the value fetch-added is the sum of a vector each time.

Answer (score 1):

> Since it is not in order, can sum.fetch_add() operates before tmpSum += val[i]? So the sum is 0 possible??

No

Regardless of the re-ordering of loads and stores as a result of the as-if rule, the program must still behave 'as-if' the code was followed in explicit order of the written instructions.

what `std::memory_order_relaxed` means is that:

- the add will occur atomically with respect to other atomic operations on sum that happen in different threads.
- the change in sum may not be observed by another thread immediately, but it will be observed very at some point soon.

Answer (score 0):

No, why should it be? The statements are executed in order, that means first the 100 add operations, and then the `fetch_add`. Since you are using an atomic I guess you are doing some multithreaded stuff. It can be that, if the function is executed multiple times in parallel, that the single `fetch_add`'s are happening in an arbitrary order.